# Android Activity MotionEvent coordinates to ImageView Canvas

Tags: java, android, drawing, android-canvas

I'd like to catch the coordinates of a touch event via 'onTouchEvent'. Now in my activity I have the following code to do that:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    try {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Point p = new Point();
                p.set((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY());

                                    // The point is added to a list here

                    return true;
        }

        updateDraw();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.wtf("Error", e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}
```

The activity's XML layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MarkLinesActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/handView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Now in the updateDraw() function the actual problem occurs. Because I try to catch 3 coordinates via the 'onTouchEvent' and draw them using a 'Path'. Unfortunately the points are always at incorrect locations. This is what is inside updateDraw():

```
Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(currentBitmap);

tempCanvas.drawBitmap(origBitmap, 0, 0, null);

tempCanvas.drawPath(p, pa);
```

This is how I create the coordinates for the path:

```
p.moveTo(points.get(currentLineState).get(0).x,    points.get(currentLineState).get(i).y);

for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
try {
    p.lineTo( (points.get(currentLineState).get(i).x),
                      (points.get(currentLineState).get(i).y) );
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
}
}
```

Note: points is defined as `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Point>>` and p being a Path instance.

The last part of updateDraw() is drawing the content created by canvas on the ImageView:

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.handView)).setImageBitmap(currentBitmap);
```

Now my question is: Is there something wrong with the way of getting the actual coordinates (I also tried using event.getX() etc.) or maybe something with the XML? I also tried extending an class from ImageView myself and draw by overriding 'onDraw' but that also created incorrect positions for the points. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map between `View` and image coordinates use `Matrix` `getImageMatrix()` method.

Comment: Do you mean calling getImageMatrix() of ImageView? I tried using mapPoints on the resulting matrix but that didn't change anything.

Comment: what do you mean saying "that didn't change anything"?

Comment: The position of the path is still incorrect. It might change something that origBitmap and currentBitmap are both rotated by 90 degrees. Does  that change something?

Comment: ok, in other words why do you want to do this? if you just want to draw over the ImageView, extend it and override its onDraw method

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally managed to get it running. I extended ImageView using a new class and in it's onDraw method I called canvas.setMatrix(getImageMatrix()). It seems like that did the trick!